# App2SD doesn't work - I don't even have the option

Tags: app2sd, samsung-stellar

So I got a Verizon Samsung Stellar (it has Android 4.0.2) a few days ago. All's going well, but I don't have the option to transfer an app to my sd card. However, I can move files etc with a file manager, so the phone recognizes the SD card is there.

On my old phone (an ancient MyTouch 4G, it was 2.3.4) there was a button in the Application Manager to move an app to the SD card. If the app didn't have App2SD supported it would be grayed out.

I called Verizon to see why I don't have this option on my newer phone (you think that with a 1GB internal hard drive and an *included* SD card they would support moving apps to your SD) and the person said that I just hold down the app name and a bar would come up with options. Holding down an app did nothing, no quick vibrations like when you move an icon on your home screen, etc. I've looked and about 80% of apps I have support App2SD so it's not that. How do I fix this? My phone is already full.